# What version of GWT to compile the gwt-gae-book project (cultureShows1.2) (http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gae-book/)

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I can not compile the project
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gae-book/downloads/list

I do not know the version of GWT that it is used to compile the project. I tried with GWT 2.0 2.2 2.3...and have many different errors (GIN principally...).

Anybody have successfully compiled this project ? If yes, can he tell me the version of gwt used ?

Tkx,

Comment: Have you tried email to the author? It looks like he last touched the project about 6 months ago, but he might still be around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This commit](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gae-book/source/detail?r=840) indicates that GWT 2.1 was used.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried the 2.1.0, but the good version is 2.1.1.

Cheers,